# Returning validation invalid login warning php script

Tags: php, mysql

I have already created a successfull login form that is connected to a database to determine whether or not a login is correct. But i would like to update this so that if an incorrect username or password is entered they will get an error message. Im just not to sure how to implement that into my existing code?...

my user login page:

```
<form action="../login.php" method="post">
<label for="login-username"><i class="icon-user"></i> <b>Username</b>    </label><br/>
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="username">
<br/>
<label for="login-password"><i class="icon-lock"></i> <b>Password</b>    </label> <br/>
<input class="form-control" type="password" name="password">
<br/>
<button type="submit" class="btn pull-right">Login</button>
</form>

<?php
if (isset($_SESSION['username'])){
 if($_SESSION['logged_in'] = 1){
echo ('Logged in as:  '. $_SESSION['username'].'    '.$_SESSION['surname']).'<br><a href="logout.php">Log out</a>';
}
}
?>
```

and the login.php it is posting to:

```
<?php

session_start();

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "gpdb";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
 }
 //echo "connection successful";

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];


$sql = "SELECT * FROM patients where Username ='$username' and Password ='$password'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$admin_user = 'admin';
$admin_password = 'admin1';

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
if ($username === $admin_user || $password === $admin_password ){
foreach($result as $row) {
//echo "PatientID " .$row["PatientID"]."<br>". "First name and Last   name: " . $row["Firstname"]. " ".$row["Surname"]. "<br/>";
$_SESSION['id'] = $row["PatientID"];
$_SESSION['username'] = $row["Firstname"];
$_SESSION['surname'] = $row["Surname"];
$_SESSION['logged_in'] = 2;
header("location: http://localhost/index.php");
die;
}
}else{ 
foreach($result as $row) {
$_SESSION['id'] = $row["PatientID"];
$_SESSION['username'] = $row["Firstname"];
$_SESSION['surname'] = $row["Surname"];
$_SESSION['logged_in'] = 1;

header("location: http://localhost/index.php");
die;
}
}
}else{
$_SESSION['logged_in'] = 0;
header("location: http://localhost/user.php");
die;
}

?>
```

Comment: Did you start the session in user login page? You're also assigning instead of comparing using `if($_SESSION['logged_in'] = 1)`

Comment: @Fred -ii-, hi yes i created the $_SESSION['logged_in'] in the login.php page. This just determines the role of the user, the code i have provided is all working but does not contain anything contributing to whether the users entry is wrong. Atm, if the user puts in a wrong username and password or non at all it just goes to the last else statement in login.php and the login page will just refresh. Im just not sure where to start with this?

Comment: as I said, you're "assigning" instead of "comparing" using `if($_SESSION['logged_in'] = 1)` add another equal sign and you should be good to go. `if($_SESSION['logged_in'] == 1)`

Comment: So, did that fix it? ^ or where are we at with this? You've also been given an answer below.

Comment: Apologies, i was trying the code below and it seemed to work, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

if ($result->num_rows > 0){
    header("location: http://localhost/index.php");

}else{
    echo "Wrong Username or Password <br />".
    '<a href="http://localhost/user.php">Go back...</a>';
}
?>
```

You may also create a `login_failure.php` page and in the else part redirect the user to that page. OR another approach is to pass the value of failure message

```
header("location: http://localhost/user.php?msg = 1");
```

and display the message at the top of login box. Get the value of 'msg'  in user.php page and apply if condition to display the message.

```
<div><?php
$msg = $_GET['msg'];
if (isset($msg)) { echo "Wrong username/password"; } ?> </div>
    <form action="../login.php" method="post">
    <label for="login-username"><i class="icon-user"></i> <b>Username</b>    </label><br/>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="username">
    <br/>
    <label for="login-password"><i class="icon-lock"></i> <b>Password</b>    </label> <br/>
    <input class="form-control" type="password" name="password">
    <br/>
    <button type="submit" class="btn pull-right">Login</button>
    </form>
```

Comment: Hi this is great thank you, I went with creating another php page. Although would you know off hand is there code for "on page reload clear a session variable?"